# PortSIP on port 80 with Letsencrypt

Tags: letsencrypt

I have PortSIP v.16 running on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine on Azure. It's running and I can get public access to it on https://x.x.x.x:8887 as specified in the manual. The next step is to get a secure connection to it via TLS, and I'm therefore trying to create a certificate with Letsencrypt. However, Letsencrypt only looks for a challenge on port 80 - not port 8887.

How can I get my PortSIP server to listen on port 80 so Letsencrypt can complete the challenge? Or how can I forward requests on port 80 to port 8887?

Answer (score 0):

Closing this. I had misunderstood how the Letsencrypt process works - it apparently creates its own webserver on port 80. It doesn't rely on any other web server which is why I didn't have to forward port 80 to 8887. I just needed to make sure that port 80 was open. I tested this with caddy.